# Creating third level associations where second level belongs_to third on Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have the following model, Purchase, on my Rails app:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  belongs_to :payment, :validate => true
  belongs_to :day, :foreign_key => :day_day, :primary_key => :day, 
    :counter_cache => true
  [...]
end
```

And I have the Day model:

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  has_many :purchases, :foreign_key => :day_day, :primary_key => :day
  [...]
end
```

I'd like to create an association between the day and the payments occurred during that day through the Purchase model. Is it possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you can give a little more detail on why your relationships are set up the way they are.

My first question is what does a `Day` object consist of? Could it be replaced by having a "purchased_on" attribute on the `Purchase` model?
If so, this can be done pretty easily through a scope on `Purchase`.

Second, the way you have it now a single `Payment` has many `Purchases`. Is this really what you mean, or do you actually want a `Purchase` that has many `Payments`?

Let me know, and I'll see if we can get something worked out for you.

Comment: Hey Adam! Thanks a lot for your help! A Day model is just a model i use to avoid making requests to 5+ tables to get the data of a single day (money coming in, products going out, raw material flow). It simply is ran every end of the day and collect the data from the purchases and stuff. The payment has_one purchase because the customer can create more than one payment (if he goes to the credit card page, then comes back, then goes again to the bank debit page) and i didn't want to end with multiple payments referencing the same purchase..

Comment: I actually stopped searching for an answer to this problem as i found some workarounds simply stopping being lazy and started making multiple requests when needed to other models. The Day model is created only once a day and i can bear with the computing cost it has when it runs! Thanks a lot for your help!